# Export highchart with free text entered as pdf

Tags: highcharts, bar-chart, export-to-pdf

I am using Highchart api to display Bar chart. And also I have one text area below that chart to enter some text for user.

I want to export this chart in pdf, but same time I want to render textarea's text in pdf.

Now I can see only charts in pdf. This is working fine.

```
<script>
$(function () {
    var listJS = <%=list4%>;
    window.chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {renderTo : 'container', type: 'column'},

        title: {
            text: 'Stacked bar chart'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['PreviousMonthutilizationforCPU', 'CurrentMonthUtilizationforCPU', 'Week2','Week2','Week3','Week4']
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'POD'
            }
        },



        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return '<b>' + this.x + '</b><br/>' +
                    this.series.name + ': ' + this.y + '<br/>' +
                    'Total: ' + this.point.stackTotal;
            }
        },
        legend: {
            reversed: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                stacking: 'normal'
            }
        },

        series: listJS,

        exporting: {
            enabled: true
        }
    });

    $("#export2pdf").click(function(){
           chart.exportChart({
               type: 'application/pdf',
               filename: 'wow-pdf'
    });
});
});

</script>
```

Comment: So you want to get something similar to this chart? http://jsfiddle.net/6m2rneL8/3/

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński ,Thank you so much for your great help!

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński I don't see the text being included in the export. Has something changed since parvid sharma accepted this?

Comment: Hi @WiSeeker, In my pdf document I can see custom text. Could you please give me some more detailed information about your issue?

Comment: Please see http://imgur.com/AqEbpRY. And, here is the exported PDF http://imgur.com/ll2SwST. Where should I expect to see the text from box below the chart?

Comment: A jsfiddle was shared as part of answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/41147831/1944091. Interestinly, I can't see the text in export there too. I checked both inside and outside firewall. Same behavior. Just a bit more detail in case you're trying something.

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński canyou please this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42560883/add-css-property-to-a-custom-text-while-creating-a-pdf-of-highcharts and help me?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can see that this topic is removed.