# Export Multiple highcharts with custom text into pdf

Tags: pdf, highcharts, textarea

I want to export multiple charts with textareas in PDF i

How will I implement in the following above code? pLease guide me

Comment: Grzegorz Blachlińsk ,please answer this by taking help of the answer which u replied in before example only.Thanks, It will be og reat help to me.

Comment: What have you tried? No code is present in regards to your statement "following above code".

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39166045/export-highchart-with-free-text-entered-as-pdf

Comment: I want to implement the code.

Comment: Parvind, in the future, please do not ask the same question multiple times on Stack Overflow. That is considered spamming and will get your questions downvoted.

Answer (score 2):

You can use my previous idea from similar topic: 
[Export highchart with free text entered as pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39166045/export-highchart-with-free-text-entered-as-pdf)

You can iterate over all of your charts and add them to your exported svg with texts related to these charts:

```
Highcharts.getSVG = function(charts, texts) {
    var svgArr = [],
        top = 0,
        width = 0,
        txt;
    Highcharts.each(charts, function(chart, i) {
        var svg = chart.getSVG();
        svg = svg.replace('<svg', '<g transform="translate(0,' + top + ')" ');
        svg = svg.replace('</svg>', '</g>');
        top += chart.chartHeight;
        width = Math.max(width, chart.chartWidth);
        svgArr.push(svg);
        txt = texts[i];
        txt = '<text x= "' + 0 + '" y = "' + (top + 20) + '" styles = "' + txt.attributes.style.value + '">' + $(txt).val() + '</text>';
        top += 60;
        svgArr.push(txt);
    });
    return '<svg height="' + top + '" width="' + width + '" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">' + svgArr.join('') + '</svg>';
  };
```

Here you can find an example how it can work: http://jsfiddle.net/6m2rneL8/32/

Comment: Thank you Grzegorz Blachliński, I got it now.