# export multiple highcharts with text area for their highcharts to multiple PDF file

Tags: pdf, highcharts

I want to export multiple highcharts with textarea to multiple pdf files.
How will I convert multiple highcharts with textarea to multiple pdf files?

```
   $(function() {
      Highcharts.getSVG = function(chart, text) {
        var svgArr = [],
          top = 0,
          width = 0,
          txt;
        var svg = chart.getSVG();
        svg = svg.replace('<svg', '<g transform="translate(0,' + top + ')" ');
        svg = svg.replace('</svg>', '</g>');

        top += chart.chartHeight;
        width = Math.max(width, chart.chartWidth);

        svgArr.push(svg);
        txt = '<text x= "' + 0 + '" y = "' + (top + 20) + '" styles = "' + text.attributes.style.value + '">' + $(text).val() + '</text>';
        top += 200;
        console.log(txt.indexOf('\n'))
        svgArr.push(txt);
        return '<svg height="' + top + '" width="' + width + '" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">' + svgArr.join('') + '</svg>';
      };
      Highcharts.getSVG = function(chart, text) {
        var svgArr = [],
          top = 0,
          width = 0,
          txt;
        var svg = chart.getSVG();
        svg = svg.replace('<svg', '<g transform="translate(0,' + top + ')" ');
        svg = svg.replace('</svg>', '</g>');

        top += chart.chartHeight;
        width = Math.max(width, chart.chartWidth);

        svgArr.push(svg);
        txt = '<text x= "' + 0 + '" y = "' + (top + 20) + '" styles = "' + text.attributes.style.value + '">' + $(text).val() + '</text>';
        top += 200;
        console.log(txt.indexOf('\n'))
        svgArr.push(txt);
        return '<svg height="' + top + '" width="' + width + '" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">' + svgArr.join('') + '</svg>';
      };

      Highcharts.exportChartWithText = function(chart, text, options) {

        // Merge the options
        options = Highcharts.merge(Highcharts.getOptions().exporting, options);

        // Post to export server
        Highcharts.post(options.url, {
          filename: options.filename || 'chart',
          type: options.type,
          width: options.width,
          svg: Highcharts.getSVG(chart, text)
        });
      };
     Highcharts.exportChartWithText = function(chart, text, options) {

        // Merge the options
        options = Highcharts.merge(Highcharts.getOptions().exporting, options);

        // Post to export server
        Highcharts.post(options.url, {
          filename: options.filename || 'chart',
          type: options.type,
          width: options.width,
          svg: Highcharts.getSVG(chart, text)
        });
      };



      chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
          renderTo: 'container',
          type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
          text: 'Stacked bar chart'
        },
        xAxis: {
          categories: ['PreviousMonthutilizationforCPU', 'CurrentMonthUtilizationforCPU', 'Week2', 'Week2', 'Week3', 'Week4']
        },
        yAxis: {
          min: 0,
          title: {
            text: 'POD'
          }
        },
        tooltip: {
          formatter: function() {
            return '<b>' + this.x + '</b><br/>' +
              this.series.name + ': ' + this.y + '<br/>' +
              'Total: ' + this.point.stackTotal;
          }
        },
        legend: {
          reversed: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
          series: {
            stacking: 'normal'
          }
        },

        series: [{
          data: [1, 2, 3, 3, 4]
        }],

        exporting: {
          enabled: true
        }
      });

       chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
          renderTo: 'container1',
          type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
          text: 'Stacked bar chart'
        },
        xAxis: {
          categories: ['PreviousMonthutilizationforCPU', 'CurrentMonthUtilizationforCPU', 'Week2', 'Week2', 'Week3', 'Week4']
        },
        yAxis: {
          min: 0,
          title: {
            text: 'POD'
          }
        },
        tooltip: {
          formatter: function() {
            return '<b>' + this.x + '</b><br/>' +
              this.series.name + ': ' + this.y + '<br/>' +
              'Total: ' + this.point.stackTotal;
          }
        },
        legend: {
          reversed: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
          series: {
            stacking: 'normal'
          }
        },

        series: [{
          data: [1, 2, 3, 3, 4]
        }],

        exporting: {
          enabled: true
        }
      });


      var text = document.getElementById('txt');

      $("#export2pdf").click(function() {
        Highcharts.exportChartWithText(chart, text, {
          type: 'application/pdf',
          filename: 'wow-pdf'
        });
      });
       $("#export2pdf").click(function() {
        Highcharts.exportChartWithText(chart, text, {
          type: 'application/pdf',
          filename: 'wow-pdf'
        });
      });
    });
```

Comment: Similar topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39171077/export-multiple-highcharts-with-custom-text-into-pdf

Comment: In text area if I enter as follows 1.Custom text1 2.Custom Text2 while exporting to pdf I am getting as  1.Custom text1 2.Custom Text2 in a single line while I need to break lines and need in another line.Could u please guide me??

Comment: I want multiple highcharts into multiple pdf with text area.My code is as follows, but not working with the above example.

Comment: I want multiple highcharts into multiple pdf with text area.My code is as follows, but not working with the above example. <div style="page-break-before:always;">
<div id="container2" style="height: 300px; width:600px"></div>
<textarea name="message" class="HC" id='2' style="width:600px; height:50px">
  Custom text for my charts 2
</textarea>
   </div>

Comment: Grzegorz Blachliński,could u help me, Please?

Comment: I want only textarea to export to pdf in the same code.? <textarea name="message"class="HC" id='2'style="width:1600px; height:350px"></textarea> and exporting I am not getting .Is there any other method to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First part of an answer is here: 
[Export Multiple highcharts with custom text into pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39171077/export-multiple-highcharts-with-custom-text-into-pdf)

To answer the second question, asked in your comment (about breaking the lines) -  you need to change the code a little bit. You may use **tspan** for breaking your lines. You should also remember about changing width of your label with every new line:

```
  Highcharts.getSVG = function(charts, texts) {
    var svgArr = [],
      top = 0,
      width = 0,
      txt,
      numberOfLines;
    Highcharts.each(charts, function(chart, i) {
      var svg = chart.getSVG();
      svg = svg.replace('<svg', '<g transform="translate(0,' + top + ')" ');
      svg = svg.replace('</svg>', '</g>');
      top += chart.chartHeight;
      width = Math.max(width, chart.chartWidth);
      svgArr.push(svg);
      txt = texts[i];
      value = $(txt).val().replace(/\n/g, '</tspan><tspan x="0" dy="1.2em">');
      numberOfLines = $(txt).val().split("\n").length;
      txt = '<text x= "' + 0 + '" y = "' + (top + 20) + '" styles = "' + txt.attributes.style.value + '"><tspan x="0" dy="1.2em">' + value + '</tspan></text>';
      top += 1.2 * 16 * numberOfLines + 20;
      svgArr.push(txt);
    });
    return '<svg height="' + top + '" width="' + width + '" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">' + svgArr.join('') + '</svg>';
  };
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6m2rneL8/35/

Comment: Great! Grzegorz Blachliński, you have helped me a lot.

Comment: I have 50 charts in my html page. Once I export all charts to pdf, then all charts rendering properly in pdf. But these charts rendering in only one page. There is no page break. So can you please help me if it is possible. Thanks @Grzegorz

Comment: I think it is whole lot different question than you asked before, you can find similar topic here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32614717/export-multiple-highcharts-to-multi-page-pdf

Comment: Yes, but the sam ecode, I hav eimplemented, is not working.

Comment: Can u please check ?

Comment: I meant to say that,page break is generated , but I have requirement to add customized textrarea with line break, but textarea with line break is not getting overwritten.How do I add textarea with line break in the same code?

Comment: Hi Grzegorz Blachliński,I m not able to capture customized textarea with line break using xepOnline.jqPlugin.js only highcharts is exported.Could u please guide me?