# Reserve space for text in exported Highchart

Tags: highcharts

We've a barchart that grows/shrinks based on data within a given container. We also allow the user to export the chart to PDF. During export, some text is placed in a pre-determined location.

When the chart is tall enough, the chart runs into the text. When I adjust the `sourceWidth` and/or `sourceHeight` the chart grows to take all the space. Essentially, I'm looking for ways to reserve some space in the exported document for the text so that the bar never runs into the text. How do I do this?

Notice the top most two blocks of the left bar running into text.
[image]

My export code is:

```
    $scope.exportPdf = function() {
        var chart = $("#group-chart").highcharts();
        var exportOptions = {
            type: "application/pdf",
            filename: "Chart",
            sourceWidth: 850,
            sourceHeight: 1100
        };
        var chartOptions = {
            yAxis: {
                gridLineWidth: 0,
                labels: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                title: {
                    text: null
                }
            }
        };
        chart.exportChart(exportOptions, chartOptions);
    };
```

I'm including some text in the `load` event of `exporting.chartOptions.chart.events` as below:

```
this.renderer.text(disclaimerText, 100, 100)
    .css({
    fontSize: "60%",
    lineHeight: "10%",
    width: "600px"
    }).add();
```

Comment: If the text is static, adjust the margin top  http://jsfiddle.net/5jvpzsqm/

Comment: Excellent. This is working very well. If you can provide this as answer, I would accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the position of the rendered text is known, you can set an exported chart's margin top.

```
 chart: {
    marginTop: 150,
    events: {
      load: function() {
        this.renderer.text('custom text', 100, 100)
          .css({
            fontSize: "60%",
            lineHeight: "10%",
            width: "600px"
          }).add();
      }
    }
  },
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/5jvpzsqm/